# Icon filename convention for Toolbar Icon

Tags: xamarin.forms

Need some help on the icon filenaming convention for Toolbar icon as below:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="IconLogout" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="IconMain" Priority="1" />
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


My Icon filename convention :

              Default size        size 40 x 40 
             ------------      -----------------
1) for iOS  : IconLogout         IconLogout-40@2x

2) for Droid: IconLogout         IconLogout
                              - create icon w 48x48 and place it in medium-density (MDPI)
```

Question :

What will the be filename convention for Xamarin forms so it will fetch the correct icon file?

a) Can I use this for (1)

filename:   Icon_Logout  ,      Icon_Logout_40@2x

How xamarin form knows which part of the filename is used as the common part?

b) what is xamarin forms filename convention?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you just use "filename.png" or "filename.jpg", and iOS will look for @2x/@3x, and Android will look in the appropriate sub-folders

See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Native_Resolutions_Retina_and_High-DPI

Comment: replace & with @. So the distinct part is &2x or &3x, So low resolution iphone will look for filename without &2x.  If I started with Icon="Icon_Logout" , and I use iphone7s, will it fetch  Icon_Logout_40@2x  if there is also Icon_Logout_80 & 2x or any file begin with Icon_Logout_80_OK &2x. Or My must Standard my 1st part of the filename before & 2x ?